# iOS: Validations receipt via AppStore vc Validation via your own server

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes

I read about it at this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

And I see that there are 2 approaches. So what from it is easy to implement ?

Comment: Passing receipt data converting in base64 at backend and validating from backend is an easy approach to implement.

Comment: Refer http://www.raywenderlich.com/23266/in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial-consumables-and-receipt-validation